# Trigger is not inserting value into correct record

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger that get a QuoteNumber from table 1 and insert it into table 2 where ShippingIdentity matches the records in both tables. The problem is the QuoteNumber is being inserted into it's own row(record) Can anyone please let me know why? Thanks.

```
ALTER TRIGGER InsertQuoteNumber
ON AccountInfo
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO ShippingInfo (QuoteNumber)
SELECT a.QuoteNumber 
FROM AccountInfo a
inner join inserted i on a.ShippingIdentity = i.ShippingIdentity 
END
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I'm using sql-server

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got it to stop putting the same QuoteNumber for all the records but it is still putting the QuoteNumber in it's own row instead of where the ShippingIdentity match 

ALTER TRIGGER ShippingQuoteNumber
 ON ShippingInfo
 after UPDATE
 AS
 BEGIN

 UPDATE ShippingInfo SET QuoteNumber = a.QuoteNumber
 FROM AccountInfo a
 INNER JOIN inserted t ON  t.ShippingIdentity = a.ShippingIdentity
END

Answer (score 0):

You use the word "insert" in your description, but I think what you mean is "update".  That is, you want to modify an existing row in `ShippingInfo` to reflect the new quote number.

The problem in your code is as simple as your choice of words.  You are using an `INSERT` command, which inserts a new row.  If you want to update an existing row, use an `UPDATE`.

Comment: When I used the UPDATE it set the same QuoteNumber for all the records instead of matching the different ShippingIdentityin each row:  ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ShippingQuoteNumber]
 ON [dbo].[ShippingInfo]
 FOR INSERT
 AS
 BEGIN

 UPDATE ShippingInfo SET QuoteNumber = a.QuoteNumber
 FROM AccountInfo a
 INNER JOIN inserted t ON  t.ShippingIdentity = a.ShippingIdentity
END

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got it to stop putting the same QuoteNumber for all the records but it is still putting the QuoteNumber in it's own row instead of where the ShippingIdentity match ALTER TRIGGER ShippingQuoteNumber ON ShippingInfo after UPDATE AS BEGIN UPDATE ShippingInfo SET QuoteNumber = a.QuoteNumber FROM AccountInfo a INNER JOIN inserted t ON t.ShippingIdentity = a.ShippingIdentity END